# Is it possible to slow down the rise time when using the DRV8412 for PWM?

Tags: pwm, texas-instruments, radiation, motordriver

I am using a [DRV8412](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8412.pdf) to drive a 36 V DC motor with 100 kHz PWM. I see a radiation issue due to sharp 100 kHz PWM to the motor. When I probe the  motor current, I see current ringing at each transition (low to high or high to low.)

Is there a way to increase the rise time of PWM (making it slow) so the smoother transition can reduce the ringing and radiated emission? From TI datasheet I do not see any recommendations or options to do that.

Is it possible to slow down the PWM edge by adding resistance to the PWM input to the driver? It wasn't clear on TI datasheet that the PWM input goes to the H-bridge directly or any other control system.

Comment: After a brief look at the datasheet, it doesn't look like you have any slew-rate control - probably cause high-efficiency (>97%) was the design criterion of this chip. You can possibly add series inductance to the motor windings, but it would be best to use a different IC that gives you the latitude to modify EMI performance if that's a requirement for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Drive appears to be fixed and internal.

You can however add LC filtering at the outputs.  This can be partial, to remove harmonics from the output, without having to filter the full PWM cycle; however, some AC losses will be incurred.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flPQMd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

If you check the simulation, notice power dissipation is also simulated; the energy in C2 is necessarily lost as heat in R1 every cycle.  A lossy (yet low resistance) L1 can also be used; ferrite beads for example are good in lower-level applications like MCU output pins, however they are not suitable at the high peak currents here, so L1 will most likely be a regular inductor type component.

Comment: Sure thanks..that would help